# Can I customize my AngularJS application to display local times?

Tags: angularjs

I am using an ASP.NET MVC / ASP.NET Web API back-end for my application. When a user updates data the time is recorded like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PutContent(int id, Content content)
    {
        if (id != content.ContentId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try
        {
            content.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            content.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            _uow.Contents.Update(content);
            _uow.Commit();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        } 
    }
```

When the user looks at the modified time they see what I assume is the server time. Is there a way that I can allow them to see the local time that the change was made?

Note that already I do some formatting but I am not sure if there is a way that I can convert the date and have this matched up with my local users who could be in any location:

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" 
   value="{{modal.data.modifiedDate | date:'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'}}" />
```

Comment: Did you try http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n?

Comment: could use IP address to get user timezone and adjust output at server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with it is always better to save the dates on server in UTC. So on the server use the method `DateTime.UtcNow`.

And while sending the data to client, if you are not custom formatting the date, i believe the date send contains the timezone information as well. AngularJS can handle that correct using `date` filter. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jHSLe/1/

Comment: look at his fiddle, that is what you should always do

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the date you are getting is in UTC, you can use the excellent Moment.js to easily convert it to local time as described here:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

Comment: I would also recommend Moment.js for it's excellent manipulating and formatting of dates.